# grab content from custom cms site and insert it in wp as pages

Tags: wordpress, web-crawler, copy-paste

I have to recreate a custom made cms site in Wordpress, I have no access to the old database.

Is there a way, to automatically grab the texts from the old site and insert it in Wordpress maintaining the hierarchy?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can export posts and pages from old site and import it to new site

using import/export options in wp-admin

Comment: The old site isn't WP

Comment: yes, te old site is not wp, it is a custom made cms, and have no export option